# jQuery Mobile with multiple columns inside listview

Tags: android, iphone, jquery-mobile

Anyone who have solved the problem to have an arbitrary number of columns inside a list view in jQuery Mobile?

What I want to achieve is basically a table representation, but with the styled list view features.

I know that the jQuery Mobile list view supports "a couple of columns" but i need to be able to use several (maybe four or five).

Or do you have any suggestions on pure CSS-frameworks to get the right iPhone "look and feel"? I've tried iWebKit, but since I would like to get rid of the navigation bar (and couldn't find any solution to this), I chose not to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `grid` code and insert listviews to columns. See in JQM docs, it works with multiple columns. I did that and it looks like a table. If you set up the listviews correctly you can get nice looks also - eg. a listview with `inset` on will make rounded corners for all columns.

Comment: You mean to place every column into its own listview which in turn is put into a column of the grid for each listview?

Comment: Yes. I just didn't use the world `listview` this many times ;) Good luck.

Comment: It worked fine! Just had some problems to have columns of different widths, but thats another question :)

Comment: I guess you'll have to CSS that by force ;)

Answer (score 1):

For columns of different widths you should take a look at this:
[960 grid on jQuery Mobile](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/)